# Smarty Template Variable inside Variable

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, smarty

I have text this stored in my database:

```
Your email is: {$email} and your name is {$name}.

$text = get from db this field;
```

I read this field from the database

I assign with smarty this:

```
$smarty->assign('text', $text);
$smarty->assign($name, 'maria');
$smarty->assign($email, 'maria@email.it');
```

and visualize in my html page with this:

```
{$text}
```

Result is:

```
Your email is: {$email} and your name is {$name}.
```

My problem is Smarty not renders a variable inside a variable.

can someone help me?

Comment: Considering the purpose of templating is to separate the tasks (between people or in time). This approach is hard to read / find for the template designer. It takes away of the template's role and puts it in the hands of the logic or Controller.

Comment: @sofl's answer is correct in offering a direct solution to exactly what you asked. Please make sure you don't shoot yourself in the foot just because you can.

Comment: The "better approach" would be to either type the string in the template or if it absolutely needs to be separated then you need to create a sub-template file and include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

```
$smarty->assign('name', 'maria');
$smarty->assign('email', 'maria@email.it');
$smarty->assign('text',$smarty->fetch('string:'.$text));
```

check out http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl for more details

**EDIT**

If you store your templates in a database, I would recommend you to read about *custom template resources* http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.custom.tpl

Answer (score 1):

Or if you use Smarty 2

```
$template = "Your email is: {$email} and your name is {$name}."

require_once( $smarty->_get_plugin_filepath( 'function', 'eval' ));
$smarty->assign('name', 'maria');
$smarty->assign('email', 'maria@email.it');

$compiled = smarty_function_eval(array('var'=>$template), $smarty);
```